# include в Smarty

Tags: php

Всем добрый день.
Со смарти не приходилось работать и есть несколько вопросов.
В php есть замечательная функция include, которой я обычно пользуюсь для подгрузки определённого контента в определённом месте на странице.

Как то же самое реализовать на смарти?
Предположим, что есть основная страница:
index.php и шаблон к нему index.tpl

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{$title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="header">header
        </div>
        <div id="menu">menu
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        {* КОНТЕНТ *}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

и пусть допустим будет файл, отображающий новости:
news.php и его шаблон news.tpl

как мне этот файл втулить на мою страницу в виде контента?
пусть условием того будет параметр из переменной взятой в GET.
index.php?cat=news - как - то так. )
За ранее извиняюсь за примитивность, я просто очень давно этим не занимался. )

Answer (score 1):

[smarty-include](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl)

Советую перечитать весь док.

Comment: Этот вариант я - то читал. Но ведь он может подключать файл ШАБЛОНОВ *.tpl.  
Где обработку событий делать? В основном файле что - ли?

Comment: Кажется нашёл. ) {include_php} ещё есть. ) Спасибо за наводку. )

Comment: Так, что - то поспешил я с выводом. Когда вызываю {include_php file='news.php'}, почему - то на странице вообще всё пропадает. Просто белый лист и всё. Кто сталкивался с подобным, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Курите error_log. Скорее всего смарти не может найти путь к вашему news.php и нужно каким то образом добавить пути для поиска файлов

Answer (score 0):

```
{php}
    // подключение php скрипта прямо
    // из шаблона
    include("/path/to/display_weather.php");
{/php}
```

А это делали?

Comment: Это делать пробовал. Но этот вариант не работал. В 3-й версии, читал, эти тэги отключены по - умолчанию. И что есть другие варианты. )

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за подсказки. Всё использовал тэг {include_php}
Просто надо было включить php тэги. :)

```
$smarty=new Smarty();
echo "Ok";
$smarty->debugging=true;
$smarty->allow_php_tag=true; //Как - то так. :)
```